# Lost partition on WD 1.5 TB external drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

My 1.5 TB WD drive failed out of nowhere and now it shows up saying "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer"
This is how it shows up on Disk Utility

[image]

This is what `sudo gpt show disk6` shows:

```
     start        size  index  contents
         0           1         PMBR
         1           1         Pri GPT header
         2          32         Pri GPT table
        34      262144      1  GPT part - E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE
    262178  2930014957         
2930277135          32         Sec GPT table
2930277167           1         Sec GPT header
```

This is what `diskutil info disk6` returns:

```
Device Identifier:        disk6
Device Node:              /dev/disk6
Part of Whole:            disk6
Device / Media Name:      Initio INIC-1610P Media
Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)
Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)
File System:              None
Content (IOContent):      GUID_partition_scheme
OS Can Be Installed:      No
Media Type:               Generic
Protocol:                 USB
SMART Status:             Not Supported
Total Size:               1.5 TB (1500301910016 Bytes) (exactly 2930277168 512-Byte-Units)
Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
Device Block Size:        512 Bytes
Read-Only Media:          No
Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)
Ejectable:                Yes
Whole:                    Yes
Internal:                 No
OS 9 Drivers:             No
Low Level Format:         Not supported
```

I don't know what to do! I tried using TestDisk, but a full scan would take 14 days.

Comment: Well you have one "Microsoft Reserved Partition". Everything else is gone. I suppose you could post the results from `sudo fdisk /dev/disk6`, but I am fairly sure it will not help. What did you expect to see in the way of file systems? I also suppose you could dump the hex values of the GUID Partition Table (GPT) to see if anything is left to recover. The command to hex dump the first 4 entries in the GPT would be `sudo dd if=/dev/disk6 count=1 skip=2 | xxd`. Post the results or use this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_entries) to read them yourself.

Comment: Have you attempted to repair the disk (not the volume) via Disk Utility? What happens?